# how can I get GST open APIs to validate my GSTIN from that?

Tags: django, rest, gstreamer

I am working on Register Users with GST number program. when a user enter their GST number it has to verify with the help of official GST open APIs so that we can find out that the user is actually registered with GST and company status. I need Gst apis on testing mode.

I had try to get Public testing API from Master GST. I Also Found this link : https://api.mastergst.com/public/search?email=savaliya.isha160%40gmail.com&gstin=33AAECB1042N2ZW

Comment: Did you get any API to test it?

Comment: Did you find the API?